# How to insert a structure or a pointer, inside a cell of a normal array? c++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

i made an array that looks like this,
int array[array_length];
now i want to enter inside one of it's cells a pointer or a struture(doesnt matter the content of these pointers/structures for now), how do i do that?

this is what i did so far:

```
const int array_length = 5;

struct Point {double _x,_y;};

void read_points(int array[array_length]);

int main(){
    int array[array_length];
        int i = array_length;   
    struct Point *temp;  
    while (i > 0) {
        temp = new (std::nothrow) struct Point;
        array[i-1] = &temp;
        if (array[i-1] == NULL) {
            cerr << "Cannot allocate memory\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i--;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Kindly show us what you have done so far so that we can help you

Comment: Why do you want to store a non-`int` in an `int` array?

Comment: i made an upgrade

Comment: i think i should just make an array of pointers?

Comment: although i would have liked better if it was possible to insert a structure in an array cell,

Comment: okay i guess chi was right, i should have changed my array to a pointer array, i didnt know that was possible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a declaration like `int array[array_length];` the int means that it's an array of int values. So you need to declare it as `Point* array[array_length];` (array of pointers to Point objects). And then your temp is already a pointer to Point objects, so `array[i-1] = temp;` is the way to put them inside the array.
So your final code may look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int array_length = 5;

struct Point {double _x,_y;};

//void read_points(int array[array_length]);

int main(){
    Point* array[array_length];
    int i = array_length;
    struct Point *temp;
    while (i > 0) {
        temp = new (std::nothrow) struct Point;
        array[i-1] = temp;
        if (array[i-1] == NULL) {
            cerr << "Cannot allocate memory\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i--;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```